# setTimeOut() solution on Twitter

Tags: jquery, twitter

I was reading John resig's blogpost: http://ejohn.org/blog/learning-from-twitter/ and I did not understand the problem with setTimeOut()  there.

**Question 1:**

Johh shared this code:

```
var outerPane = $details.find(".details-pane-outer"),
    didScroll = false;

$(window).scroll(function() {
    didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
    if ( didScroll ) {
        didScroll = false;
        // Check your page position and then
        // Load in more results
    }
}, 250);
```

Where is caching used here? I assume when didScroll is true, then outerPane variable will be used instead of re-searching the DOM, am I right?

---

**Question 2:**

In the comment section Michael shared a code:

```
var timer = 0;

$(window).scroll(function () {
if (timer) {
clearTimeout(timer);
}

// Use a buffer so we don't call myCallback too often.
timer = setTimeout(myCallback, 100);
});
```

and said: "*Instead of setting up an interval, the callback is only ever fired when it needs to be. Saves a few extra calls to the callback, and any overhead from the extra logic inside the scroll handler should be fairly minimal.*"

My question is: setTimeOut() will return a timerID which will be used by clearTimeOut to clear. Now with this setTimeout(myCallback, 100) function after every 100 mili second myCallBack function will be used, isn't it? Moreover, when the scroll event will fire the timer will be cleared and never set again, so what is the purpose of using it?

---

Sorry for my confusions. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1:**

`outerPane` is only ever fetched once, regardless of any other value.  The commented out lines would be where this variable would be used.  His point is simply that `$(selector)` multiple times will always be slower just reusing the result and calling that only once.  The code above will always have the `outerPane` variable anywhere that needs it, and it will be super fast.

**Question 2:**

Well, this code is kind of wrong.  Let me fix it:

```
var timer = null;

$(window).scroll(function () {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }

  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    timer = null; // Added this line.
    mycallback();
  }, 100);
});
```

The point of this is to only execute your big chunk of JavaScript (in `mycallback()`) when the user has actually stopped scrolling.  `mycallback()` will only get called when no scroll events have happened for 100ms.

So when a scroll happens, first it checks to see if there is a an unfired timeout, and if there is cancel it.  This will happen if multiple scroll events happen less than 100ms apart.  Then it sets a new timer to fire 100ms from now, which will clear out `timer` and fire `mycallback()`.

This prevents `mycallback()` from running until no scroll events happen for 100ms.  The advantage is that if `mycallback()` takes a long time, it will never interrupt the smooth scrolling of the browser.

However, in the case of Twitter (like Resig is explaining) this approach won't work.  In Twitter's case they need to move things around the screen on every scroll event because they reposition things on the screen as you scroll.  So they do need to that calculation every single time the scroll event is fired in order to keep the window looking right as you scroll down.  But also when you it this way, you have to make sure your JS is super fast because it will be executed many times over and over while the user scrolls around (Hence the explanation of jQuery element caching).

Answer (score 0):

@ Question 2:

The code `if (timer) { clearTimeout(timer); }` is easy to missunderstand, because the used syntax, in my humble opinion, is wrong. I think the code must be as follows below:

```
if (timer != null) { clearTimeout(timer); }
```

because after a clearTimeout, the variable 'timer' will be cleaned. You can try it if you would made an `alert(timer);` after 'clearTimeout()'.

Comment: Maybe it is a good idea use -in tthis case- 'timer > 0' instead of 'timer != null'. After that you should reset the value to 0 again.

Comment: This wasn't known to me :-) thanks for sharing......But still I have my confusion on setTimeOut() function. Michael said it will be fired only when it needs to be but I see it will be fired after every 100 mili seconds.....

Comment: As a matter of fact, the code from the original author is wrong. Look at Squeezy's answer for a fix.

Answer (score 0):

@ Question 1:

I read your related link and I think the answer to your question is `if ( didScroll ) {`. This query prevents that your code will be executed all time, even if it is not necessary. But I'm not sure to 100%.

Comment: ahh...that make sense. didScroll is sitting in top of the long method and preventing execution when executing the function is not necessary.